# SSL Error Handler WebView Android

Tags: android, webview, google-play, android-security, sslerrorhandler

When I try to publish my app, the Google Play Console says that I have a vulnerability in my app due to SSL Error Handler. I followed the Google Help Center solution https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7071387, and tried to publish again, but no success. I got in touch with Google Play Support, and they have answered me:

> I took a look at your app, and version PET App of 10 has the following class, which contains a vulnerable version of SslErrorHandler:

And here is the code I'm using to handle the SslError:

```
@Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, final SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SigpetActivity.this);
            String message = "SSL Certificate error.";
            switch (error.getPrimaryError()) {
                case SslError.SSL_UNTRUSTED:
                    message = "The certificate authority is not trusted.";
                    break;
                case SslError.SSL_EXPIRED:
                    message = "The certificate has expired.";
                    break;
                case SslError.SSL_IDMISMATCH:
                    message = "The certificate Hostname mismatch.";
                    break;
                case SslError.SSL_NOTYETVALID:
                    message = "The certificate is not yet valid.";
                    break;
            }
            builder.setMessage(message+" Clique em 'CONTINUAR' para permitir o acesso ao Sigpet");
            builder.setPositiveButton("continuar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    handler.proceed();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    handler.cancel();
                    finish();
                }
            });
            final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
```

I'm using no third party library for this, just android webkit WebClient.

How can I fix it to let them allow me to publish my app?

Comment: have you found the solution?

Comment: Actually no, I'm not opening the page inside my app anymore and it "solved". I simply can't force the app to open a page with problems with ssl certificate inside the WebView otherwise Google Play notify me about it.

Comment: for later, I have replied at this topic https://stackoverflow.com/a/68720821/11119281

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that Google doesn't like you calling `proceed()` or `cancel()` asynchronously in an `onClick` callback. Instead, you should do it synchronously in the `onReceivedSslError()` method itself.

Comment: do you have solution for this