# Android App is not approved with SSL Error Handler

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-play, android-security

I released a production Android app last month, but I had trouble with the SSL Error Handler.

I followed Stackoverfollow's and Google's tutorials, however Google doesn't still approve my app (note: this QA is not a duplicate).

1. https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7071387
2. [SSL Error Handler WebView Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51561977/ssl-error-handler-webview-android)

My code is implemented the following:

Any Fragment or Activity that uses WebViewClient, I've controlled SSL Error like this

```
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            LogI("onReceivedSslError: " + error.getCertificate());
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            String message;
            switch (error.getPrimaryError()) {
                case SslError.SSL_UNTRUSTED:
                    message = "The certificate authority is not trusted.";
                    break;
                case SslError.SSL_EXPIRED:
                    message = "The certificate has expired.";
                    break;
                case SslError.SSL_IDMISMATCH:
                    message = "The certificate Hostname mismatch.";
                    break;
                case SslError.SSL_NOTYETVALID:
                    message = "The certificate is not yet valid.";
                    break;
                case SslError.SSL_DATE_INVALID:
                    message = "The date of the certificate is invalid.";
                    break;
                default:
                    message = "A generic error occurred.";
                    break;
            }
            message += " Do you want to continue anyway?";
            alertDialog.setTitle("SSL Certificate Error");
            alertDialog.setMessage(message);
            alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", (dialog, which) -> handler.proceed());
            alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", (dialog, which) -> handler.cancel());
            alertDialog.show();
        }
```

So, Why is my app not approved? What should I do next?

Thank you for your advice!

Update 1:
I released my app in 2019 and updated it many times (there was no problem). But from 2021/5 I've got this problem.

Comment: Check this https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7071387

Comment: @Eishon our team've also read this and implemented, but you can see the result that is shown above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May these errors are from old APKs, AABs version, remove/deactivate it before submitting new APKs, AABs

Answer (score 1):

you have to call either `handler.cancel();` (thats for your case) or `super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);` straight inside `onReceivedSslError`. [HERE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onReceivedSslError(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.SslErrorHandler,%20android.net.http.SslError)) you have some doc, in which:

> The host application must call either SslErrorHandler#cancel or SslErrorHandler#proceed

and also

> Application overrides of this method may display custom error pages or silently log issues, but it is strongly recommended to always call SslErrorHandler#cancel and never allow proceeding past errors.

without any of these calls some Google bot which checks apps may think, that you are disabling any SSL validation at all, which may be insecure for user

Comment: if onReceivedSslError() occurs, I show a popup that has 2 buttons "Cancel" and "OK", those are equivalent handler.cancel() handler.proceed().
I dont know why the Google Bot does not accept it.

Comment: seems like `handler` should be called "soon" after `onReceivedSslError` gets called. your dialog takes some time for draw and waaay more time for user decision. bot won't "understand" this, waits for `hander` call in millisecs

Comment: Thank you, but I tried my apk that is the same with published apk on Google Play, until now I have not solved this problem yet.
I would like to post it to Twitter community, do you have any suggest for this?

Comment: have you tried to put APK in play store with `handler.proceed()` or `handler.cancel()` call straight inside `onReceivedSslError`? if you are still getting refusion then I don't know how to "fix" that... community may help in such case, worth trying

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I used in my App and it was accepted. The only difference I am seeing is the try-catch block. My suggestion will be to try a simpler version on Play Store first, then update that with the specific type error message.

```
@Override
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
    try{
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(PaymentActivity.this);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.notification_error_ssl_cert_invalid);
        builder.setPositiveButton("continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                handler.proceed();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                handler.cancel();
            }
        });
        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: if the matter is time, let me try to your answer and @snachmsm's one. Thank you and I will update my solution.

Comment: this does not work, although I contacted with Google Play team