# Google Play Internal Testing App Rejected

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, google-play-console, policy

I try to release apk in Internal Testing mode, but my app was rejected with reason "Not adhering to Google Play Developer Program policies".
I have done all the set up, but my app always rejected. Have you ever had this case, and how to fix it ?

Comment: check your developer email. A message should be there telling about what policy was broken. Or you can contact google support. They will give you reply within 2 business day.

Comment: if you're using Webview, be careful with it. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68342153/11119281