# Adding multiple apk or aab to "Not Included" section in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, android-security

When I want to release a production version, I can only add a app bundle to Not Included section. So How can I add multiple app bundle to that section? Is this a bug of GG Play?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make sure to let **Staged roll-out** 100%

It works for me

[image]

Comment: This did the trick for us as well. Google was rejecting our update because the previous release was still active. Setting rollout to 100% made the old release inactive.